# Expected value of inverse?

Tags: expected-value, delta-method

If I have a random variable $V$ that is normally distributed with some $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then what is the expected value of $1/V$? I tried doing by delta method, and I get expected value $1/\mu$, but I also read that this is not the correct result.

To clarify:

My random variable $V$ is a variable that can be measured. The data given back to us are mean and standard deviation of the measurements. (I understand that I should be using the t-distribution to best model it, as we only have an average of 4 reads, but I am trying to work it out for the Normal case first.)

The value $V$ is indicative of protein binding to ligand. I wish to understand fractional occupancy ($\alpha = \frac{current signal}{saturation signal}$), in which case I need to know the value of $V$ at saturation, which also can be estimated from the data (take the max value of all values present, this will be a consistent under-estimation). Therefore, if $V \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, I expect $\alpha \sim N(\frac{\mu}{max}, \frac{\sigma^2}{max^2})$. I hope I did the math right.

From the Hill equation,
$$
\alpha = \frac{\mbox{ligand}^n}{\mbox{ligand}^n + K_d} ,
$$
therefore 
$$
K_d = \frac{\mbox{ligand}^n}{\alpha} - \mbox{ligand}^n.
$$

Therefore, if $V$ were a random variable, then alpha is a random variable, therefore Kd should be a random variable. I'm trying to find how to model $K_d$ here. My thought was to use the delta method to get an approximation, and that is how I led myself to this question I've posted here.

Comment: This question at math.SE may help, although it also only references Wikipedia and does not give a proof (if you have access to the book by Johnson, Kotz & Balakrishnan cited on the Wikipedia page, this may help): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution

Comment: @Glen_b: Ah yes, I understand that the delta method always gives us an approximation. I think this is sufficient for us, since we are dealing with real-world data. We are modelling the binding coefficient of a ligand as a random variable, which is proportional to the inverse of the fluorescence signal produced.

Comment: Allow me to include additional information into the question.

Comment: Many thanks to @Quantibex for helping me with edits!

Comment: ericmjl - I just noticed I typed the inequality the wrong way around in my previous comment. I decided to delete it so as not to mislead anyone with it. The correct inequality is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#General_inequality_in_a_probabilistic_setting) -- i.e. when $E(1/X)$ exists and variance is not zero $E(X)E(1/X)>1$.

Comment: Oh, I meant to say, since your values are *measurements*, you should be careful of specifying normality; normal distributions have density at 0, while measurements don't.

Comment: Great, this is really great, I'm learning a lot as I go along here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that the expectation of the inverse of a normal variable can easily be infinite!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your values are measurements, I assume the actual density close to 0 is not an issue and we can safely assume convergence for the Taylor expansion.

> (I understand that I should be using the t-distribution to best model it, as we only have an average of 4 reads, but I am trying to work it out for the Normal case first.)

This appears to be a common misconception. Having small samples doesn't cause approximately normal data (or its mean) to have a t-distribution; if your reasons for assuming approximate normality are good, small samples doesn't change that.

Your discussion doesn't make it clear how $V$ relates to $\alpha$.

It's *also* not clear how finding the expectation of $1/V$ tells you about $K_d$. I feel like there are important details missing.

In any case, I'll do the expansion:
\begin{align}
g(X) &= g(\mu_X + X - \mu_X)  \\
     &= g(\mu_X) + (X - \mu_X)\cdot g'(\mu_X) + \frac{(X - \mu_X)^2}{2!}\cdot g''(\mu_X) + \frac{(X - \mu_X)^3}{3!}\cdot g'''(\mu_X) + ...
\end{align}
Taking expectations term by term:
\begin{align}
E(g(X)) &= g(\mu_X) + g'(\mu_X)\cdot E(X - \mu_X) + \frac{g''(\mu_X)}{2}\cdot E[(X - \mu_X)^2] +  ...  \\
        &=g(\mu_X) + 0 + g''(\mu_X)/2\cdot \text{Var}(X) + ...   \\
        &\approx g(\mu_X) + g''(\mu_X)/2 \cdot\text{Var}(X) 
\end{align}
When $g(X) = 1/X$,

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\ \ \approx \frac{1}{\mu_X} - \frac{1}{2\mu_X^2} \sigma^2_X $

An approximation for the variance can also be obtained.

Comment: alpha is proportional to V, but Kd is proportional to 1/alpha, that is how the variables are related to one another. V is the binding signal, alpha is the fractional binding, which is V/Vmax (where Vmax is also estimated from data), and Kd is proportional to 1/alpha by the Hill equation. 

In any case, your answer was really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how those equations suggest $K_d$ is proportional to $1/\alpha$. Similarly if $\alpha=V/V_\text{max}$ and both are random variables, you can't really treat $V_\text{max}$ as a constant in computing expectations: for example $E(X/Y)\neq E(X)/E(Y)$

Comment: Ah, I see. There was an error made when my question was edited to introduce LaTeX formatting. I have updated the equation properly.

Comment: If $\text{ligand}^n$ is a constant, say $c$, then $K_d=c(1/\alpha -1)$ which isn't $\propto 1/\alpha$

Comment: I also see your point on Vmax... So how would you treat it in this case?

Comment: But for the purposes of computing the expected value, I could ignore the c, and ignore the -1 term, or am I wrong here? Specifically, the c would provide a proportionality term, but the expected value of -1 would be -1, which is shifting the expected value.

Comment: You can't really *ignore* it. But yes, you can easily account for it.